Combining multiple nullable collection in Kotlin
I am working on a kotlin function that needs to combine a series of nullable collections into a single output collection. The obvious solution is brute force. Use a series of if/else statements to figure out which collections are not null and combine them accordingly. However, this solution is messy and error prone. What I'm looking for is an existing kotlin function that can take n+1 nullable collections and output a new collection with their combined contents. Does something like this exist, or do I simply have to do this the hard way?
Example:
//list1:['a','b','c']
//list2:null
//list3:['x','y']
func combineStuff(list1:List<String>?, list2:List<String>?, list3:List<String>? )
{
    return list1 + list2 + list3
    //['a','b','c','x','y']
}


The simplest option may be to use the .orEmpty() method available on all Collection<T>? values:
list1.orEmpty() + list2.orEmpty() + list3.orEmpty()

list.orEmpty() return the list itself, if it's non-null. Otherwise, it returns an empty list. In other words, using it is equivalent to (list ?: emptyList()).
See also the official API documentation

Using varargs for the function arguments, you can filter easily:
fun <T> combineStuff(vararg list: Iterable<T>?): List<T> =
    list
        .filterNotNull()
        .flatten()

The argument might as well be Iterable instead of List for better flexibility.

If you're fine with the intermediate allocation, you can directly do listOfNotNull(list1, list2, …).flatten()

Shouldn't the first line be this: fun <T> combineStuff(vararg list: Iterable<T>?): List<T> = list. (plus better line breaks)

@gpunto: That's also very concise, it should be another answer.

@Leviathan, yes, oops. I can fix the line breaks when back at a computer.

Can you explain why you added .asIterable()? filterNotNull already returns an Iterable and the following flatten has no other overloads, so adding this seems redundant.

@Leviathan I was on my phone and misremembered what type Array.filterNotNull() returns.

Another way to do so is to leverage listOfNotNull from the stdlib:
listOfNotNull(list1, list2, …).flatten()

This creates an intermediate collection (the list of lists), which is then flattened.
